# Chef logs with test kitchen

Tags: chef-infra

I am using test kitchen and has a depandant cookbook that my cook book is using.

The dependant cookbook has a resource which has a log-

---

```
Chef::Log.fatal("Fetching the md5 for #{file_name} at #{uri} resulted in an error #{response.code}")
```

---

When I converge my cookbook, I don't see this log.
What can i do to see this log.

I used below command for converging-
kitchen converge -l debug.

Comment: That appears to be an error logged for when something goes wrong, so break whatever it is that that log entry is logging for.

Answer (score 3):

`kitchen -l debug` used to work but now that only sets the log level for Kitchen, not Chef. You need to add the log level to your kitchen config:

```
provisioner:
  name: whatever
  log_level: debug
```